# Using Rails' build() method through a renamed association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a Message model containing

```
belongs_to :from, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :to, class_name: "User"
```

When I do something like

```
user.messages.build(text: "my message")
```

how can I ensure the user put into the "from" association is the building user? How does Rails know whether to put it into "from" or "to"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct way to set up the `message` model would be like this:

```
belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'
```

Your migration would be like

```
create_table :messages do |t|
  t.integer :sender_id
  t.integer :recipient_id
  t.timestamps
end
```

Then, in the `user` model:

```
has_many :messages, :foreign_key => :sender_id
```

Then, in the `message form` you could set the `sender` like this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :sender_id, value: current_user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :recipient_id, value: @user.id %>
```

You could also set the parameters like in your example in the question like this:

```
Message.create(sender_id: 1, recipient_id: 3)
```

This should let you do things like:

```
@message.sender.username
@message.recipient.username
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume the foreign keys on `Message` would be `from_id`, and `to_id`.

If you renamed the association, when you define `messages` association in your `User` model, you need to specify the `foreign_key`.

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :received_messages, foreign_key: :to_id, class_name: "Message"
  has_many :sent_messages, foreign_key: :from_id, class_name: "Message"
end
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Otherwise Rails will assume you have `user_id` on `Message` and I think it would raise error because your `messages` table does not have `user_id` column (not tested).